# C# Menu strip is gone in .cs [design]

Tags: c#, designer

All my items in my menu strip disappeared and is blank. Yet all the Code in the Designer portion is there. Is there any way to restore it? Or do I have to manually add it all back in?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use some code versioning system, just make a revert, if you don't this is good lesson, which teaches to begin to use one.

Answer (score 2):

I got it back I just went back into the designer.cs part of the code and re-referenced the original components... ie:
`this.menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.fileToolStripMenuItem});`

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the design, recompile, and open the designer again to see if that helps - solved my problem one time.

Comment: @Gilad Try to be serious, If you don't know the answer don't say anything.

Comment: Sorry, it's just made me laugh. Never happens again

Comment: @saber I mean the answer does work sometimes, but it still made me laugh :)

Comment: @GauravMall :D I was so mad.